# Is it worth the effort to split one multilanguage wordpress domain into multiple domains?

Tags: seo, wordpress

My current website on Wordpress is using WPML. I've made a choice to use

- https://domain.pl/ for English Content
- https://domain.pl/pl for Polish Content

The goal was to have directory based redirects. Since I own .xyz domain now which is global along with other domains such us .support/.solutions etc I was wondering if it's worth the effort to split them so that

- https://domain.pl gets Polish Content
- https://domain.xyz gets English Content and goes global

The effort i'm talking about is doing all the redirects, reconfigurations etc. Will it give me much higher SEO boost or should I just focus on adding more and more content? I have a feeling that https://domain.pl/pl doesn't have much visibility because of the "/pl" (and as such Google webmasters also treats it differently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is worth it. although you can use meta tags for location and language, but it seems Google treats ccTLDs (.pl, .us) differently and they get better rank in local searches than international searches.

I think it is worth it to have a gTLD (.xyz) for your English, or international versions.

You can also provide all languages on your .xyz, then redirect the .pl domain to domain.xyz/pl/ or pl.domain.xyz.

Comment: So I thought :-) Oh well will need to do this I guess. Few days of work. Thanks. Is pl.domain.xyz better then domain.pl/pl ?

Comment: It depends on your target audience. .pl is better if it is a local business. for better, faster results on Google, you should tell it that you are moving your site, see this https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106

Comment: I am not moving the website. I'm using both so in other words I can't tell google about redirect because it's not gonna happen. https://domain.pl will keep PL stuff and https://domain.xyz will keep ENG stuff.